# not assignable to 'android.app.activity' extends application

Tags: android, android-manifest, adobecreativesdk

I am implementing Adobe Creative SDK. I am getting the following error in in my my manifest file:

```
'com.example.nick.avierytest2.MainActivity is not assignable to android.app.activity'
```

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is my main activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Application implements IAdobeAuthClientCredentials {

/* Be sure to fill in the two strings below. */
private static final String CREATIVE_SDK_CLIENT_ID = "";
private static final String CREATIVE_SDK_CLIENT_SECRET = "";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    AdobeCSDKFoundation.initializeCSDKFoundation(
            getApplicationContext(),
            AdobeAuthIMSEnvironment.AdobeAuthIMSEnvironmentProductionUS
    );
}

@Override
public String getClientID() {
    return CREATIVE_SDK_CLIENT_ID;
}

@Override
public String getClientSecret() {
    return CREATIVE_SDK_CLIENT_SECRET;
}
```

}

Every other time I have seen this question on stackoverflow it was someone trying to declare a fragment in the manifest but that is not the problem here and I have not been able to find the solution.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> MainActivity extends Application
> ```

Of course an `Application` is not assignable to an `Activity`.

Either change this to `MainActivity extends Activity`, or move the `android:name=".MainActivity"` reference in the manifest to the `application` tag (and remove that `activity`). In the latter case also consider renaming the class from `MainActivity` to e.g. `MyApplication`.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it!

Comment: i didn't get this :(